# RadioButtonList selection IndexChanged

Tags: asp.net

My Scenario,

When i select the option in list i need to perform some action like Textbox should be disabled. But i don find my breakpoint pointing to that action to be performed.Pls help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the SelectedIndexChanged event does not fire that is so because you'vent set the AutoPostBack to true.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Code

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    TextBox4.Enabled = false;
 }
```